# returning a list in CompletableFuture after joining

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, completable-future

I have this piece of code:

```
List<PendingWorkflowReturn> pendingWorkflowReturns = new ArrayList<>();

        CompletableFuture<List<PendingWorkflowReturn>> cf1 
                = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> 
                pendingWorkflows(menageReturn.getId(),"a"));

        CompletableFuture<List<PendingWorkflowReturn>> cf2
                = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->
                pendingWorkflows(menageReturn.getId(),"b"));


        List<PendingWorkflowReturn> combined = Stream.of(cf1,cf2)
                .map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I woud like to return a List, but instead is returning a list of a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to concatenate the two lists in order, you can `flatMap` them  into the stream:

```
    List<PendingWorkflowReturn> combined = Stream.of(cf1,cf2)
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .flatMap(List::stream) // this replaces each list with the elements of the list in the stream
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alternatively, you could use a custom collector:

```
    List<PendingWorkflowReturn> combined = Stream.of(cf1,cf2)
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::addAll, ArrayList::addAll);
```

Comment: `collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::addAll, ArrayList::addAll)` == `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`

Comment: @Eugene I'm afraid not. `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` is equivalent to `collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add, ArrayList::addAll)` — the second argument is `add` rather than `addAll`. It has the same outcome as the original code in the question: it produces a nested `List<List<PendingWorkflowReturn>>`.

Comment: sorry, I meant like this: `Stream.of(cf1,cf2).map(CompletableFuture::join).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`

Comment: Sure, that's similar to my first example.

Comment: For two futures, you can also use the simple way, `List<PendingWorkflowReturn> combined = Stream.concat(cf1.join().stream(), cf2.join().stream()) .collect(Collectors.toList());` On the other hand, why dealing with a completable future at all, when we’re ending up at a stream operation anyway. Just use a stream operation in the first place: `List<PendingWorkflowReturn> combined = Stream.of("a", "b").parallel().flatMap(arg -> pendingWorkflows(menageReturn.getId(), arg).stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());`